# plotly js ranges for logaritmic yaxis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to not show log numbers after 10 and show next values like 20,30,40, type is log needed

[image: problem]

[codepen](https://codepen.io/awsicker/pen/VwPVegr)

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [1,10,20,40, 14, 12, 10, null, 15],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  connectgaps: true
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [16, null, 13, 10, 8, null, 11, 12],
  mode: 'lines',
  connectgaps: true
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Connect the Gaps Between Data',
  showlegend: false,
  yaxis: {
  type: 'log',
 }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: There is link on codepen

Comment: I suggest to use D3 proper instead of Plotly, since it does not support functional hooks on tick formatting (if I understand their documentation right: https://plotly.com/javascript/tick-formatting/)

Comment: Oh sad, thanks for yours investigation